# Docker-compose: what are the listening sockets "injected" into containers on IP 127.0.0.11 are used for?

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, dns, docker-compose

By pure accident I noticed that containers started as services through `docker-compose` contain two sockets that are connected to the host's `dockerd` process, but don't seem to be the "Docker socket" for contacting the Docker daemon API. These sockets do not appear for containers started with a plain `docker run ...`.

To reproduce, first create a docker-compose yaml file, `composer-woes.yaml` with these contents:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: 'ubuntu'
    pid: host
    command: ['/bin/sleep', '100000000']
```

Next, bring up the "ubuntu" service: `docker-compose -f composer-woes.yaml up`.

Then enter the service container, install tools, and check what's open:

```sh
$ docker exec -it ${PWD##*/}_ubuntu_1 /bin/bash
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools iproute2
# netstat -tulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39627        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:58047        0.0.0.0:*                           -
# ss -tulp
Netid           State             Recv-Q            Send-Q                          Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port            
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                                  127.0.0.11:58047                              0.0.0.0:*               
tcp             LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.11:39627                              0.0.0.0:*
# cat /proc/self/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 0B00007F:9ACB 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 139272 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

Notice how both `netstat` and `ss` are unable to find the process having opened these sockets. We see that the strange socket has inode #139272. We'll need it to now scan the host for a process with an fd referencing this inode.

In your host, finally do this magic bash code; remember to substitute the inode # you see in your test:

```sh
sudo bash -c "sock=socket:[139272]; for proc in /proc/*; do for fd in \$proc/fd/*; do readlink \$fd | grep -q -F \$sock && echo \$proc: \$sock ... \$(cat \$proc/cmdline|sed 's/\o0/ /g'); done; done"
/proc/1375: socket:[139272] ... /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

So, the two UDP/TCP sockets **inside** a Docker container brought up by `docker-compose` actually belong to the host's `dockerd` process **outside** the Docker container.

- question part #1: **what are these sockets used for?** The only reference to `127.0.0.11` I could find is about [Embedded DNS server in user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/).
- question part #2: how are these sockets are actually getting into the container? Please note that they belong to `dockerd`, not to a `containerd-shim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some more digging, trying many different search queries I've finally found two posts [how does Docker Embedded DNS resolver work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707573/how-does-docker-embedded-dns-resolver-work/50730336), [Answer to: Forward incoming external DNS packets to the embedded docker DNS](https://serverfault.com/a/826424) that indirectly explain what is going on, see references below for details.

In short: the udp and tcp ports we see are in fact the Docker engine's embedded DNS server ports. Additional iptables port forwarding rules then ensure that clients talking to 127.0.0.11:53 are "wired up" to these dynamically allocated ports of the embedded DNS server.