# DNS resolution in docker containers

Tags: docker, dns, certbot

[**environment**]

- CentOS 7
- Docker 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe

I have a failing **cerbot** (let's encrypt client) inside a **docker** container. It looks like `acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org`is not resolvable **from the container** but is resolvable **from the host** (the most probable cause). I am used to the fact that containers inherit from the host's DNS parameters but, in the case of AWS EC2 instances, there seems to be some subtilities

### DNS Manual setting

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-243 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search eu-west-2.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

Based on this and some elements from **AWS console**, I tried to add these address manually

```sh
docker run --dns 172.31.0.2 --dns 172.65.32.248
```

(I probably did not find the proper DNS)

### An inelegant fix

Using the **host's network** solves the problem

```sh
docker run --network="host"
```

But I just don't quite understand why. Is it a matter of network interface used in `--network="host"`. Here are the one available:

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-243 ~]$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:d2:81:33:16:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:9c:c8:d4:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-d15fdfe7243b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e8:56:81:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Would it be because `--network="host"` induce using `eth0` instead of `docker0`? How can I resolve `acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org` from `docker0`?

### Detailed error

```sh
An unexpected error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Try again

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f55dcc4a130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f55dcc4a130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f55dcc4a130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again'))
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

Comment: +1 to **[Suhas NM] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988037/7878132)**. For more detailed explanation, you can refer to :
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730336/7878132 
2. https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41022

Answer (score 26):

Looks like DNS resolution inside docker is not working properly.

For linux systems, DNS resolution happens using `/etc/resolv.conf` file, check this file inside your container, if it has invalid DNS, then your container won't be able to resolve hostnames.

Docker uses a property set in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file(on host) for populating entries in `/etc/resolv.conf` inside container.

update the value of this property in /etc/docker/daemon.json file in host machine:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Note: This change requires restarting docker to take effect, also existing containers have to be removed and created again.

Restarting Docker:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

removing containers:

```
sudo docker stop <container-name/id>
sudo docker rm <container-name/id>
```

You can add multiple DNS server ip addresses, separate each one with a comma - check [here](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062) to get a list of DNS server ip addresses

Cheers!!

Comment: Need to be in same docker network too, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35691865

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Suhas has solved a problem when I'm trying to lauch a "python:latest" container image and installing a requirements.txt list inside of it.

This trick is very useful because some images you cannot write anything to resolv.conf because you may not have privilegies to add new dependent root layers there.

exemple of error:

```
" > [6/6] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:                                                                                 
#0 14.69 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa212596110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask/  "
```

If you guys get some compose stack to run something like Flask server or any python xxxx.py program you must add those DNS entries in your host's docker daemon.json file. Create it if it not exists.

## create a DNS entry in your docker daemon:

```
sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
} 
EOF
```

## check you firewall status first (RHEL based - disable for testing or add an rule for your compose port)

```
    systemctl status firewalld
```

## restart host's docker service

```
    systemctl restart docker
    systemctl daemon-reload
```

## then run you stack

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```