# Python Debian Docker image can't update anymore

Tags: python, docker, debian-buster

Since yesterday evening (14NOV2020), I'm no longer able to update my container (python:3.9-buster)

```
$ winpty docker run -it python:3.9-buster //bin/bash
root@3a7825a70263:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is the content of the /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
root@3a7825a70263:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20201012T070000Z buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20201012T070000Z buster/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20201012T070000Z buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Is there anything known about this issue?

**EDIT 1:**
As per @madzohan comment, I've tried to add `[trusted=yes]` in the /etc/apt/sources.list, but after that change I still can't update.

```
root@3a7825a70263:/# echo deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main | tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
root@3a7825a70263:/# echo deb [trusted=yes] http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
root@3a7825a70263:/# echo deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main


root@3a7825a70263:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [trusted=yes] http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

root@3a7825a70263:/# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates Release
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates Release
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main all Packages
Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main all Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.110 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**EDIT 2:**
As per some resources found [on internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842456/3807092), I've tried to perform some pruning on docker, but after that change I still can't update:

```
docker image prune -f
docker system prune -f
docker container prune -f
```

**EDIT 3:**
The resolution was to wait ... :-/
Now if if try to update it, it works.
I guess someone at Debian forgot to push some files on http://deb.debian.org/debian and fixed it this afternoon (since some files seems to have been updated after 15NOV2020 14:00:00)

```
$ winpty docker run -it python:3.9-buster //bin/bash
root@6c0a161ec04b:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [248 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7906 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [7856 B]
Fetched 8401 kB in 4s (2021 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@6c0a161ec04b:/#
```

Comment: Did you try set deb [trusted=yes] ... in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: @madzohan, thanks for replying. I've tried your proposal, but apparently it doesn't work - see my edit

Comment: My DNS resolve both hosts to different IPs. Just to try/debug: can you force both domains to be `security.debian.org` => `151.101.64.204` and `deb.debian.org` => `151.101.122.132` ?

Comment: yep try to run  `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` and|or set dns server https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988037/3033586

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```sh
docker image prune -f
docker system prune -f
docker container prune -f
```

Comment: Didn't solve it for me, but thanks for the commands!